# Strategy for notification checking

Tags: express, angular

Is there a recommended strategy for checking of notifications within my AngularJS app?

By 'notification' I'm talking about message alerts that are to be displayed to a user when they're logged into the application.

My plan is to notify the user of unread notifications in the app's NavBar as shown below:

[image: NavBar notifications]

My app communicates with my restFul API (written using Node.js, express, MongoDB), so I anticipate that new notification will be written to a MongoDB collection with details the user the notification is intended for.

What I'm unsure about is how the AngularJS application will check for notifications once a user is logged on.  I could call my API for unread notifications every time the user navigates from one path to another but that seems simplistic and it wouldn't work if a new notification occurs whilst a user is viewing a page.

Another way would be some sort of timer system that checked, say, every 30 seconds.  But this would results in unnecessary polling of my API when there aren't any new notification for a user.

So, wondering if there is a recommended strategy.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is a solution but it is very inefficient. The solution to your problem are websockets. Websockets is a technology that provides a full-duplex bidirectional communication between your clients and your server. So you can send messages from your server to your connected clients. Your server maintains an array of connected clients and you just have to know which ID you need to send a message to it.

For your stack, the best solution I have came to is Socket.io http://socket.io
It also have cool features. For example, you can "observe" models, so if a model change in your database, for example an update to a user profile is made, you can trigger an event and automagically send a message to your client. This client get and handles the notification and do something, like put a badge on your alerts icon.

Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Superb, thanks @Jorge.  Sockets appear to be just what I need and I've been reading about socket.io and it looks ideal.  Many thanks.